# Computer with high specs lags for some reason. Don't know why

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, cpu

My computer has pretty decent specs.

Windows 10.1
i5 3.7ghz processor
16GB Ram
4GB Nvidia GTX 980 Graphics Card
CCleaner is run regularly.

Over the last few weeks the computer has begun lagging and I am not sure why. Start up takes forever now. Once I log in it also takes longer than usual to load desktop and for icons to pop up. Takes longer than usual for Chrome to open. Sometimes the mouse lags when its being moved across screen and programs that used to run flawlessly go unresponsive (eventually come back) even if they are the only things open. When these symptoms occur, CPU fan speeds up to full blast, however my CPU monitor/activity monitor show normal levels for CPU. This doesn't happen all the time. It comes and goes, but has been coming more and more lately.

I'm not sure why this is happening. It was never a problem a few weeks ago. I would appreciate your guys help. Any ideas? Thanks.

P.S. recently a program went unresponsive and windows popped up with "your computer is low on memory" although the activity monitor seemed to disagree with that, if it provides any clues.

Comment: Have you checked your HDD health, And do you have a pagefile set? Could you add a picture when its lagging of the Resource monitor?

Comment: Thermal throttling due to overheat.

Comment: Is this a new PC? If so, your PC is updating in the background and will lag for a few days as it pulls updates and downloads them slowly but surely. I always forget this process each time I get a new PC. Also have you started installing all of your programs? Could also be a virus that is using your PC. Run MS Security Essentials, do all updates and a scan. Also download Malwarebytes free version and do updates and complete scan.

Answer (score 0):

> When these symptoms occur, CPU fan speeds up to full blast, however my
>   CPU monitor/activity monitor show normal levels for CPU

Many of the more recent CPU monitors that I've seen will only give you an at the moment look of what is going on with your computer.  A monitor with some graphing capabilities will probably help a bit more.  [ProcExp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) has some graphing capabilities, it's free and pretty good.  Finding out which program is spawning and using up all of your resources should be one of the things you look for first.  There's a good chance that your AV has updated itself and the update messed something up.

Personally, I would NEVER use a program such as CCleaner.  I used to be a field tech and it can potentially cause a lot of problems.  Not sure about now, but wouldn't trust it anyways, they can't know about how every other developer out there installs stuff in the registry so there's a potential for error.

Also, if you hold shift and right-click on the desktop, you'll see an option that should say: "Open command window here".  Click on that and then run this command:

```
tasklist > Taskinformation.txt
```

Then open up the newly created Taskinformation.txt file and past the results.  This will show us everything running on your computer at the time it was ran.

Answer (score -1):

as i see i think your problem is coming from your CPU because u said you CPU FAN will get to full speed , did u clean your cpu fan from dust ? and did u changed the cpu Silicone Paste ? maybe yours is too old and need to be replaced . the high temperature will cause this problem , and there is other things that can cause this problem like the .exe files that are running in your background check the task manager when this happen u can see what .exe ( application ) are using your CPU or Hard disk drive so maybe you will find the problem that cause because of an application running in background or even maybe windows defender its self sometimes i check the application that are running in background and saw windows defender are using too much hard disk drive and cpu or sometimes system application in task manager will use too much cpu . u have to check this things first then give us some more information that we can help you to fix the problem .

Comment: and for sure your hard disk drive can cause this problem too maybe your hard disk drive is damaged but when u talk about the cpu fan speed change at that moment it will be 90% because of high cpu usage by an application in background or high cpu temperature because of dust in your cpu fan and heatsink or your cpu silicone paste have to be changed because after a while they will not transfer the temperature from cpu to the heatsink !